# How do I solve IDE is running on jre not on jdk in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

System health 
This IDE is running on a Java JRE instead of a full Java SDK.
This does not work debugging will not work.
I'm getting these warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your PHAT variable, if check your PHAT it will look like this :
 C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0\bin

so what you have to do is:

Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.

Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.

Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value for the PATH variable:

C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin